# Can you retrieve and store a file from a backend server before searching for the nginx location?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

**The Problem**

I'm using the HLS module in Nginx Plus for streaming .mp4 files, using the following config:

```
    location /hls {
        hls;
        hls_fragment 10s;
        hls_buffers 10 10m;
        hls_mp4_buffer_size 1m;
        hls_mp4_max_buffer_size 10m;
        alias /var/www/vod/cache;
    }
```

Everything works fine when the .mp4 file is present in `/var/www/vod/cache`.  When the client requests `http://example.com/hls/file.mp4.m3u8` the HLS module generates the m3u8 playlist on the fly and returns it.

However, I would prefer to not store all of the mp4 files on the streaming server, and instead store the files on a backend storage server.  Ideally the mp4 files will only be retrieved from the storage server and stored locally when a client requests a particular video (to be removed sometime later by a cron job).  Using proxy_store I am able to retrieve the mp4 files and store them locally using a configuration like:

```
    location @fetch_content {
        internal;
        rewrite ^/hls(.*).mp4.m3u8$ $1.mp4 break;
        proxy_pass         http://example-storage.com;
        proxy_store        on;
        proxy_store_access user:rw group:rw all:r;
        proxy_temp_path    /tmp;
        root /var/www/vod/cache;
    }
```

The problem with using proxy_pass is that nginx returns the mp4 file directly to the client, not the m3u8 playlist.

Is it in any way possible to have nginx retrieve and store the mp4 file, and then use the HLS module to generate the m3u8 playlist file?  Or another way of putting it, can I check for the existence of the mp4 file, if not found retrieve & store it, and then hit the /hls location which will use the HLS module to stream the file?

Since this is Nginx Plus I cannot write a module.  I can only use the included modules, see here https://www.nginx.com/products/technical-specs/

Comment: I don't think such non-trivial and unorthodox logic is already implemented there ;-) Why don't you simply mount your remote server as a disk volume? Make nginx think all files are local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx Plus includes the 3rd party [Lua module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) and I was able to retrieve the mp4 file from the backend server using Lua before directing to the /hls location.